# How to obtain all three Strongholds?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iii-morrowind

I know about [the Glitch that allows to be a Telvanni and Hlaalu member at the same time](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Redoran_or_Telvanni_and_Hlaalu), though I haven't tested it yet, and one can [cheat ones way into all houses](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Tes3Mod:PCJoinFaction). But since the last stronghold quests involve the other two house's strongholds, I'm afraid that simply joining all houses and doing the quests will somehow screw up all but the last stronghold.

So, how to proceed to obtain all three strongholds in full extension? I'm not opposed to cheating, though achieving this as honest as possible is preferred.

**edit** I'm also fine using a mod, if you can suggest one that solves this without much interference<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup> actually, interference that modifies the dialogues such that the Nerevarine joining all three houses sounds more plausible wouldn't be that bad...

Answer (score 3):

I hope this helps

http://www.gamefaqs.com/xbox/915084-the-elder-scrolls-iii-morrowind-game-of-the-year/faqs/35803

> 3. Location : Tel Vos/Just outside Balmora
>
> Involves minor glitch House Telvanni : Kill Raynasa Rethan.  Issued by
>   Master Aryon House Hlaalu :  Being member of house hlaalu
>
> Way around:  To avoid this, complete the quest to kill Raynasa Rethan
>   first, and then you can use the glitch to join House Hlaalu. This way
>   you get to complete the House Telvanni quest, and Raynasa's stronghold
>   will be empty, allowing you to take possession of it.
>
> 6. Location : Tel Vos/Gnisis/Morag Tong Hall
>
> Morag Tong:  Grandmaster writ for Baladas Demevanni.  Issued by any MT
>   quest giver. House Telvanni : Convince Baladas to join the house. 
>   Issued by Master Aryon
>
> Fighters Guild :  Kill Telvanni Agents.  Issued by Eydis Fire-Eye
>   House Redoran : Halt mining operation.  Issued by Garisa Llethri
>
> This is the quest that caused me to start from scratch.  When you
>   travel to the Caldera Ebony mines, DO NOT FREE ANY OF THE SLAVES just
>   to be safe.  You can free some, but there is one slave in Slave Shack
>   1 called Dahleena, who is a female Khajit.  She must still be  in that
>   shack later, in order for you to complete a house redoran quest given
>   by Garisa Llethri.   Note:  It is still possible to complete the quest
>   if you have already freed Dahleena. You can kill the two men in
>   charge, but you will  not get a reward.
>
> Playing as a high elf, I had advanced to the rank of wizard in House
>   Telvanni.  I then learned that I needed a mouth to advance further. 
>   Once I had my mouth, i automatically advanced to Master, without
>   asking.  Once you have the rank of Master in House Telvanni, you
>   cannot advance any further, which meant I could not become
>   Arch-Magister.  To avoid this, you MUST get a mouth when you are still
>   a spellwright.  That way, you will advance automatically to Wizard,
>   and then you can ask whoever your sponsor is about advancement, and
>   they will tell you about the opportunity to become the new
>   Arch-magister.
>
> Another glitch, mentioned earlier, by killing Orvas Dren (Duke's
>   brother) and then talking to Vedam Dren about "Commona Tong", he will
>   make you a member of House Hlaalu, regardless of what other house you
>   are in. However, if you are a member, a character named Raynasa
>   Rethan, who should be in the Hlaalu stronghold just outside Balmora,
>   will not be there and this causes you to be unable to complete a quest
>   from Master Aryon that requires you to kill her.

And this:

http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Redoran_or_Telvanni_and_Hlaalu

> It's actually possible to be a member of House Hlaalu and one other
>   house at the same time. If you join House Telvanni or House Redoran
>   first, then slay Orvas Dren or convince him to allow you to become
>   Hlaalu Hortator (you will do this for the Main Quest), you'll be able
>   to speak with Duke Vedam Dren about the Camonna Tong, and receive the
>   message, Yes, I heard that you were the Hortator of House Hlaalu. You
>   could not hold that rank if Orvas Dren did not wish it. Since you
>   already have some agreement with Orvas Dren, I will name you the new
>   Grandmaster of House Hlaalu. This is followed by a raise in Hlaalu
>   rank, which can be repeated for more free promotions. If you check
>   then, you'll see that you are a Retainer in House Hlaalu and can do
>   the quests, although some conflict, like e.g. Odirniran/Telvanni at
>   Odirniran, where being in both Telvanni and Hlaalu you'll have to kill
>   everyone there; also Rethan Manor will appear and it is required that
>   you kill the owner of it. It is, however, impossible to join both
>   House Redoran and House Telvanni without cheating or modding. You can
>   acquire two strongholds, but Vedam Dren won't issue you another
>   contract, so you'll have to steal it from him then unbuild the Hlaalu
>   stronghold via the console: set stronghold to 0 [edit]Notes
>
> PC Only This bug is fixed by the Morrowind Patch Project. When
>   enabled, the topic Camonna Tong is not available when speaking to
>   Vedam Dren. To avoid some confusion, you need to have heard of the
>   topic Camonna Tong before this is possible. To access this, talk to
>   Larrius Varro at Moonmoth Legion Fort and he will give you a quest
>   looking for bad people. Then speak to most commoners about bad people
>   and they will mention the name of the crime syndicate. Then you should
>   be able to speak to the Duke. Every time you click on the Camonna Tong
>   topic, you jump two ranks in the House Hlaalu.